# Setting text entry setting in ubuntu 16.04 using terminal

Tags: command-line, language-support, input-language

Is there anyway to set text entry setting using terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 ? I mean to set key combination for changing source from EN to another language.

Comment: Just as a hint in case you don't know: There already is such a key combination. It's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Yes I know, But I had to change it a while ago, and now it seems that there is a problem, because everytime I go to Systems settings to specify the key combination the panel instantly shuts down I'm not sure why, I think there is a problem in the Ubuntu itself so  I tried to figure out how to do it using command line.

Answer (score 1):

Taking my own settings as an example. Currently I have:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us')]
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current
uint32 0
```

The zero (0) response to the second command means that my current input language is the first one, i.e. Swedish. To change it to the second input language (English (US)) from terminal I can do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
```

Comment: Yes I get you thanks man, but in other words, can I set the key combination for changing source of language using command line? (Not change the source using command line)

Comment: @HamzehHasan: Well, I saw your comment under the question... I would suggest that you start _System Settings_ with the terminal command `unity-control-center`. Then go to _Text Entry_, try to change the source switching shortcut, and show us possible error messages in the terminal window if it fails again.